# Add button to DeckPage

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I would like to create a GUI extension for Experience Manager in Tridion 2011 to add a new button to the WorkflowDeckPage, any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Could you give a few details of what you have already tried?

Answer (score 4):

See if this helps, Bart has written a post on adding unanswered SO questions to his Dashboard.
http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dashboard-extension

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have already checked that post but my aim is to extend the already existing WorkflowDeckPage rather than create a new one, nevertheless, I will check the post again.

Comment: Emma, perhaps update your post to better inform exactly what the requirement is. It does state "add a new button" but not what you want that button to do (such as extend xyz functionality). Thanks

Comment: What we would like to do it to add a new  "whereused" button to the WorkflowDeckPage so it is possible to check where the component related to a workflow activity is used by callind the "whereused" command. A similar feature to this is already included in Tridion 2013 but we are currently working with Tridion 2011 so we would like to add this feature before we migrate to the new version. We have create an extension to add the code to the Workflowpanel control and that works fine but I cannot figure out how to add the button to the Workflowpanel control by using an extension.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assume you are trying to extend WorkflowPanel. Currently there are no extension points in this panel (like ExtendableArea or extendable controls).
So you can only create script on your own risk which dynamically over js adds new Button to WorkflowPanel. This script can be added to "Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Controls.WorkflowPanel" configuration group via groups extensibility mechanism.